# How to properly use onResume with static variables in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have made an app which uses a static variable: `public static String[] katefthinseisTomeis;`
I am overriding the `onResume()` method as so:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (katefthinseisTomeis == null) {
            changeActivity(this, LauncherActivity.class, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    }
```

This is line 51 where the following error I explain occurs

```
for (String s: katefthinseisTomeis) {
```

Sometimes I get this kind of error, telling me that `katefthinsiTomeis` is a null array

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3815)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3977)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2374)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8249)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:589)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1071)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
  at com.symplyapps.pernas.KatefthinsiActivity.getWidgets (KatefthinsiActivity.java:51)
  at com.symplyapps.pernas.KatefthinsiActivity.onCreate (KatefthinsiActivity.java:43)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8130)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8110)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1343)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3781)
```

I am suspecting that my `if` statement does not actually run when I want it to because it comes after `super.onResume();` callback

Is that the case?
Am I using the `onResume` method correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've told us about "line 51," but you haven't given us enough information to tell when line 51 gets invoked -- is it in `changeActivity`?  The implementation of `super.onResume`?

Answer (score 0):

Just initialized, `katefthinseisTomeis` ,

like `public static String[] katefthinseisTomeis = new String[]{};`

OR

put whole code section of line 51, that is i think is `for loop` into `if condition` like...

```
if (katefthinseisTomeis != null){
   for (String s: katefthinseisTomeis) {
    ...
   }
}
```